# Django: Adding 2 variables and getting a response on the same page

Tags: django, python-3.x

Any help would be greatly appreciated

### index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
    <div>
        <h1>Welcome Home</h1>
        <form action="{% url 'calc:home' %}" method="GET">
        <!-- {% csrf_token %} -->
            Enter 1st Number : <input type="text" name="num1"><br><br>
            Enter 2nd Number : <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Add"><br><br>

        </form>
        Result of the game is : {{result}}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home_view(request):
    if request.GET.get('num1'):
        val1 = int(request.GET.get("num1"))
        val2 = int(request.GET.get("num2"))
        res = val1 + val2
    return render(request, 'calc/index.html',{'result':res})
```

### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'calc'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_view, name='home'),
]
```

i get this error when running the server: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'res' referenced before assignment

Comment: `res` is in the `return` statement, but it's only defined if the code in the `if` block i executed.  Define a default value for res _before_ the `if` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help. Basically you are using a variable outside of it's scope. you defined res in "if" block but called outside "if" though it was not present in that scope.So you should first assign a default value.

```
def home_view(request):
    res=0
    if request.GET.get('num1'):
        val1 = int(request.GET.get("num1"))
        val2 = int(request.GET.get("num2"))
        res = val1 + val2
    return render(request, 'calc/index.html',{'result':res})
```

Comment: This is right, but the OP would benefit also from better error handling, it seems. Under what conditions is `num1` not defined? If it is not defined, what path should the code take?

Comment: @BrianDant I understand your concern and i am completely agree with it.But i had that  ```UnboundLocalError``` in my mind when i was answering the question.

Comment: Right. My comment was not to critique your answer but to note for the OP and others that some issues remain.

Comment: @BrianDant Agreed !